# ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag convert to class wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

How I can convert like:

```
var me = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag as ListBoxItem as Data;
```

_

```
public class Data {
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
        }
```

---

```
 <Button Click="PlayMedia" Tag="{Binding}"  Content="Play" />
```

Comment: This question doesnt even make any sense. `ListBoxItem` would never be castable to `Data`. Not to mention that ListBoxItem doesnt even have anything like a url or title to bind to. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried to get url of audio by button click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that this code is in the PlayMedia event handler, you can do:

```
var button = sender as Button;
var data = button.Tag as Data;
```

If the button is contained in a ListBoxItem, then you'd have to use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to find it up the visual tree, starting with the button.